# C#, VS2010 - Changing font and other properties?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, fonts, label

Creating a text editor just to try and hone my programming skills some more. I have the winform opening new text files, saving them and the usual undo, redo, copy, paste etc etc. However. I'm now trying to change the font.

When you click the "change font" button in the menu strip, a new form appears and loads all available fonts you can use into a list box.

```
List<string> fonts = new List<string>();

        foreach (FontFamily font in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families)
        {
            fonts.Add(font.Name);
        }

        listboxfont.DataSource = fonts;
```

Now before I edit the text on the other page, I wanted to edit a sample label to test everything is okay!

After some research, I come across many bits of code like this..

```
lblsample.Font = new Font(listboxfont.SelectedItem, 12);
```

I might be wrong, but I see no reason why I can't use the selected item from the list box, which IS the fonts and use that to edit the label however it is giving me the error..

> "Text_editor.font does not contain a constructor that takes 2
>   arguments.

Have tried and tried but no luck. Can anybody help?

Comment: Two problems.  You are using the wrong Font class, spell out System.Drawing.Font.  And you are forgetting to use SelectedItem.ToString().

Answer (score 1):

It is because `listboxfont.SelectedItem` is an `object`. You need to cast it to a `string` so:

```
lblsample.Font = new Font((string)listboxfont.SelectedItem, 12);
```

or if you prefer:

```
lblsample.Font = new Font(listboxfont.SelectedItem.ToString(), 12);
```

That should do the trick!

**UPDATE - Full example**

Add **listbox** named `listboxfont`

Add **label** named `lblsample`

Add **button** named `btnPreview`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> fonts = new List<string>();

    foreach (FontFamily font in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families)
    {
        fonts.Add(font.Name);
    }
    listboxfont.DataSource = fonts;
}

private void btnPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblsample.Font = new Font(listboxfont.SelectedItem.ToString(), 12);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response however, im still getting the same error message? Also, do I have to put the size in there or can i just specify the font and not the size?

Comment: I have copied / pasted your code and the solution above and it works perfectly? I will paste whole code so you can see it working.

Comment: Thank you very much for persevering! However i STILL can't get it working! :( I feel like im either incredibly stupid or im missing somgthing very obvious. I have checked over where the code is set time and time again and im still getting

"Error 1 'Text_Editor.Font' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments C:\Users\...\Desktop\C#\Text Editor\Text Editor\Text Editor\Font.cs 38 30 Text Editor

Comment: What control is your Text_Editor control? My example is working with a Label control but it sounds as though your Text_Editor may need something different? Is it a Rich Text Editor?

Comment: Okay, so i have a label, a button and a listbox. the event is when the list box is changed, to get the selected item to change the label's font? If that makes sense? 

Here is the code..

    private void listboxfont_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            lblsample.Font = new Font(listboxfont.SelectedItem.ToString(), 12);
        }

I have no idea if it is a rich text editor HOWEVER it will need to be at some point. although i am only changing the lblsample, i will be applying this code to change the selected text in another form (the main text editor)

Comment: @NicholasMordecai - To make life easier I've shared my project example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8xq7e9k1teo9rk/FontDemo.zip please let me know if that answers your question?

Comment: @NicholasMordecai - Did you manage to look at the project I posted on DropBox? I want to remove it and did it work on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a variable named `font` in your `Text_editor` form. (note the casing.. all lowercase!)

OR

The message you typed in your question has a typo. Is it `Text_editor.fonts does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments.`? If yes, then you have used your `fonts` variable wrongly, which is not of `Font` type, but instead is of `List<string>` type.

Name your variables properly, and it should start working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lblsample.Font = new Font(listboxfont.SelectedItem.ToString(), 12.0f);
```

The Font constructor requests a String and a float

> public Font(
>       string familyName,
>       float emSize
>   )

Comment: Copied your code and still no luck! Its still saying it doesnt take two arguments. Not sure however, what i am meant to do with the second piece of code? Thanks, Nick

Comment: The 2nd one shows what the constructor of the Font need.  
Are your imports correct (are you using the right Font-class) and isn't there a type in your code?

Comment: @NicholasMordecai Try this: In VS mouse-over the Font after the '= new' and check what it says. If there's no IntelliSense, retype Font and the ( and check what VS says you to fill in